# Android Jetpack Compse TextField - R.string.default_error_message issue with Automation

Tags: android, automation, android-jetpack-compose

Issue with below versions of compose

Jetpack Compose version: 1.0.0-beta09 and up

Jetpack Compose component used: TextField.kt, TextFieldImpl.kt, Strings.android.k

We have automation app which runs our client app for automation test cases. In automation app, compose library there is a string resource R.string.default_error_message.

Steps to Reproduce or Code Sample to Reproduce:

1. When automation apk runs, its going to look up the resource id default_error_message(0x7f0020003) into the client apk
2. In client apk this resource id is allocated to some other resource for instance array or color
3. Hence the app is crashing because of some other resource type.

Noted: Our automation app runs perfectly until the compose version 1.0.0-beta08 because default_error_message was not localised.

Crash log:
[image]

Comment: Can you please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? [See here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See [/editing-help#code](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Comment: Try using keys in the compose view. If using LazyColumn/Row/Grid use itemsIndexed instead of item or use key of compose.